# How to call ctools modal window from mycustom.tpl.php?

Tags: 7, chaos-tool-suite

I need to show a modal window on click from my mycustom.tpl.php

Here is my code in mycustom.tpl.php

```
<a href="/modal/nojs" class="ctools-use-modal ctools-use-modal-processed">False Positiv1e</a>
```

In my module file :

```
$items['modal/%ctools_js'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'modal_callback',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

 return $items;
}

function modal_callback($ajax) {
    ctools_include('ajax');
    ctools_include('modal');
    ctools_modal_add_js();

    $form_state = array(
      'ajax' => TRUE,
      'title' => t('MyModule Modal Form'),
    );

    // Use ctools to generate ajax instructions for the browser to create
    // a form in a modal popup.
    $output = ctools_modal_form_wrapper('modal_form', $form_state);
    // If the form has been submitted, there may be additional instructions
    // such as dismissing the modal popup.
    if (!empty($form_state['ajax_commands'])) {
      $output = $form_state['ajax_commands'];
    }

    // Return the ajax instructions to the browser via ajax_render().
    print ajax_render($output);
    drupal_exit();

}
function modal_form($form, $form_state) {
  $form = array();

  $form['new_link_text'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Link text'),
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Submit'),
  );

  return $form;
}
```

But when I am clicking on the button, Modal window Breaks and print $output array as below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to include below code in your `mycustom.tpl.php` also.

```
ctools_include('ajax');
ctools_include('modal');
ctools_modal_add_js();
```

Comment: I added it but still it is breaking

Comment: Have you cleared cache after adding this?

Comment: Yes I added it in tpl also..but same result